# Error log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: grails, log4j, rabbitmq

I’ve narrowed down the error and have created a sample app that shows the error. The app is here https://github.com/Omnipresent/2.5.3 The error seems to happen when `:rabbitmq:1.0.0` plugin is used. When this plugin is used, `grails test run-app` shows the error below.

```
| Error log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext).
| Error log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
| Error log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/2.5.3
```

But this error does not happen when app is run in dev environment `grails dev run-app`

I am not sure how to resolve this error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Knowing nothing about grails, my assumption would be that you could setup log4j.  see http://docs.grails.org/2.3.7/guide/conf.html#logging

Comment: What does your config.groovy look like?